# Formatting or conversion issue

Tags: database, string, vb.net, type-conversion, integer

I have a line of code saving a value to a database. The database class handles the saving of the data and is sound, the code I'm having an issue with is:

```
With New xdTableName 
    .Name = "Name"
    .DayOfYear = Format(DayOfYear, "000")
    .FullString = "Name" & Format(DayOfYear, "000") & Format(Number, "0000")
    .Save
End With
```

All values for the table are saved as string, DayOfYear is an integer at first. I've tried DayOfYear.ToString.PadLeft(3, "0"c), DayOfYear.ToString("D3"), and maybe some others. Number is an integer as well and saves correctly as the left padded value of the integer it represents but for some reason DayOfYear will not save correctly. It should be saving as 012 but it only saves as 12 in both the FullString and the DayOfYear columns. Why? Even when using the same function as the Number value it still doesn't save correctly. The database column is a varchar(3) and shouldn't have any issue holding 012 as the saved data.

Comment: It is usual to include in a question like this that you know that you should not store numbers as strings, and explain why you can't format the data for display in the user interface.

Answer (score 0):

Your class only needs 2 properties for this example. Keep numbers as numbers, you can format them as you like when the need to be displayed.

Override `ToString` for the `FullString` and just call `ToString` on the `xdTableName`. This way, you are not storing redundant data.

Provide a parameterized constructor to easily flesh out a stable `xdTableName`.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click() Handles Button1.Click
    Dim TN As New xdTableName("Name", Now.DayOfYear)
    Debug.Print(TN.ToString)
    TN.Save()
End Sub

Public Class xdTableName
    Public Property Name As String
    Public Property DayOfYear As Integer

    Public Sub New(TName As String, TDay As Integer)
        Name = TName
        DayOfYear = TDay
    End Sub

    Public Overrides Function ToString() As String
        Return "{Name} {DayOfYear:000}"
    End Function

    Public Sub Save()
        'code to save
    End Sub
End Class
```